# Fast way to convert from cv::Mat to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm wondering if there is a quick way to convert from Mat to QImage. I have the following class for conversion:

```
VideoReader::VideoReader() {
    cap = VideoCapture( CV_CAP_ANY );
}

QImage VideoReader::getFrame() {
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        return;

    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;

    QImage dest = QImage((uchar*)frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    return dest;
}
```

This code works, but the getFrame() method takes roughly 20 milliseconds to complete. I would need something working at least twice as fast. Are there any ways I could optimize this/ any alternate conversion methods that would work quicker?

Thanks!

Comment: remove `if (waitKey(30) >= 0) return;` which takes roughly 30 ms

Comment: Thanks, still takes around 15 milliseconds, must be camera latency.

Comment: `waitKey(1)` consumes about 5-10 ms on typical windows systems, afaik. Cameras typically block the capturing call if no image isn't ready yet, so if your camera has, for example, 30 fps, just calling `cap >> frame` should take about 33 ms (if nothing else consumes time between two calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waitKey(30)` will pause your code for about 30 milliseconds.

This line doesn't make much sense in that function, so you should better remove it. Creating a QImage the way you do should not take much more than some microseconds, because no image is copied etc... However `cap >> frame` could take some time, depending on your capturing device (but you can't do much against that).

If you really need the `waitKey` you should use `waitKey(1)` to not waste much time there.